# How do I support existing deep link routes using Branch

Tags: branch.io

My app (Android) has some existing parameter-based deep link routing.

In the Branch docs, I read the following.

> If your app already supports deep linking using URI paths, you can
>   populate the $deeplink_path, $ios_deeplink_path or
>   $android_deeplink_path link parameters with the URI path of the
>   content to be displayed within the app. When the Branch SDK receives a
>   link containing one of these parameters it will automatically load the
>   specified URI path.
>
> In your app’s Manifest, add this meta-data key to the definition of
>   the Activity you want to show when a link to content is opened.

```
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.auto_link_path" 
android:value="custom/path/*,another/path/" />
```

What exactly would this auto_link_path look like for these real world examples:.

“myapp/#/news/*”
“myapp/login”
“myapp/#”

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.auto_link_path" android:value="myapp/#/news/*,myapp/login,myapp/#" />
```